# Getting id of div

Tags: javascript, jquery

1) I am rendering messeages according to JSON. Firstly, I need to show only 3 information from that JSON (JSON has 6 attrs). When user click on the rendered message, it should show additional information like description and I need get id of that div... Problem is, I cannot access that id...
I have main div messages, and then message_items are added to this div according to json. When I am trying to get ID of that div, it writes undefined... 
My code looks like:
2) How to store additional information about that div which I dont want to be visible?

```
$(".messages").on('click','.message__item', function(e) {

  documentView.clearContent();

  var targetElement = event.target || event.srcElement;
        alert(targetElement);

        var id = $(this).attr("id"); // DOES NOT WORK - UNDEFINED
        alert(contentPanelId);

    const data = {
      title: $(this).find(".title").text(),
      date: $(this).find(".date").text(),
      desc: document.getElementById("descr").value,
      createdBy: document.getElementById("createdBy").value,
      id: targetElement.id // DOES NOT WORK, UNDEFINED
    };
    documentView.renderDocument(data);
});


export const fillDocuments = (data) => {

    console.log("DATA. "+ data);

    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){

        const markup = `
          <div class="message__item id=${data[i].id}>
              <img src="../img/copy.svg" class="item-type">
          <div class="title">
              ${data[i].title}
          </div>
          <div class="date">
             ${formatTimeForMessages(data[i].uploadDatetime)}
          </div>
          <div class="read">
              XY
          </div> 
          // THIS DOES NOT WORK FOR ME AGAIN
          <input type="hidden" id="descr" value="${data[i].description}"></input>
          <input type="hidden" id="createdBy" value="Someone"/>
      </div>`;

      console.log("MRK "+ markup);

      elements.messages.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", markup);
    }
};
```

Comment: id should have quotes arround its value `<div class="message__item id="${data[i].id}">`

Comment: Did not help :(

Comment: One problem is you didn't close the quotes for class value and the attributes aren't being rendered properly as a result. Inspect one of those in elements inspector in browser dev tools and you'll see they are broken

Comment: The other is you can't repeat ID in a page...they are unique by definition. Use same approach you did for `title`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your didn't close the class quote on near "message__item" name. And how store data in a way that isn't visible? use data attribute, se [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes). Bellow a working example.

```js
$(".messages").on('click','.message__item', function(e) {

  ///documentView.clearContent();

  var targetElement = event.target || event.srcElement;
        alert(targetElement.nodeName);
    console.log(this);
        var id = $(this).attr("id"); // DOES NOT WORK - UNDEFINED
        alert(id);
        alert(this.dataset.title);

    const data = {
      title: $(this).find(".title").text(),
      date: $(this).find(".date").text(),
      desc: document.getElementById("descr").value,
      createdBy: document.getElementById("createdBy").value,
      id: targetElement.id // DOES NOT WORK, UNDEFINED
    };
    //documentView.renderDocument(data);
});


var fillDocuments = (data) => {

    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){

        const markup = `
          <div class="message__item" data-title="${data[i].title}" id=${data[i].id}>
              <img src="../img/copy.svg" class="item-type">
          <div class="title">
              ${data[i].title}
          </div>
          <div class="date">
             ${(data[i].uploadDatetime)}
          </div>
          <div class="read">
              XY
          </div> 
          // THIS DOES NOT WORK FOR ME AGAIN
          <input type="hidden" id="descr" value="${data[i].description}"></input>
          <input type="hidden" id="createdBy" value="Someone"/>
      </div>`;

      $("#messages").get(0).insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", markup);
    }
};

fillDocuments([
  {id:1, uploadDatetime:Date(), title: 'Title here', description: 'Desc...'}
])
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="messages" class="messages">

</div>
```